# ArcMap ModelBuilder has tools blank on editing model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

When opening previously made models the tools appear blank. I cannot enter/edit the tools.

I run on ArcGIS 10.4 with a basic license.

The installation is new and the problem is persistent with all models.

[image: Model appearance on editing]

Comment: If the "installation is new" I would first try to Repair your install, and if no luck, then uninstall/reinstall.  What OS version are you using?  Have you checked it against the 10.4 System Requirements?

Comment: This also happened to me when updating to 10.4. This was due to some bug according to Esri. Try changing windows regional settings to format English(US) (https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3527-format-regional-language-change.html)

Comment: Changing region didn't fix it. And since I have 0 administrator rights on my workstation this simple issue can prove rather timedemanding :( I am on windows 10 (64bit), which is be supported.